# Bayes rule and conditional - marginal factorisation (joint posterior)

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I have some confusion regarding Bayes rule for joint posterior (I think primarily due to the context in which notations are used)

Let $P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X)$ be a joint posterior over the parameter space $\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}$.

Then, the application of Bayes rule should yield:

$P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X) = \frac{L(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X) . P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})}{P(\theta_{2})} = \frac{L(\theta_{1} | \theta_{2}, X).P(\theta_{2} | X).P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})}{P(\theta_{2})}$

But $P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2}) = P(\theta_{1} | \theta_{2}) P(\theta_{2})$

This gives

$\frac{L(\theta_{1} | \theta_{2}, X).P(\theta_{2} | X).P(\theta_{1} | \theta_{2}) P(\theta_{2})}{P(\theta_{2})}$ = $L(\theta_{1} | \theta_{2}, X).P(\theta_{2} | X).P(\theta_{1} | \theta_{2})$

I wonder if the above expression is correct?

Comment: No, L cannot be conditional on a parameter but only on X.

Comment: Why do you have $P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X) = \frac{L(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X) . P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})}{P(\theta_{2})}$ and not $= \frac{L(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X) . P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})}{P(X)}$ or $= \frac{L(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X) . P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})}{\int\int L(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2} | X) . P(\theta_{1}, \theta_{2})\, d\theta_1 \, d\theta_2}$ ?

Comment: @Henry You are correct - that was a typo. Since the inference is to be made for the parameter $\theta$, the integration is wrt $\theta$

Comment: @utobi That cannot be true.

Comment: could you define then what is the non-standard notation $L(\theta_1|\theta,X)$ means? L is not a density w.r.t $\theta$...